# Mass-assigning attributes in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, crud, mass-assignment

I try to create new user using Active Admin and I get:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id, approved_at_date, approved_at_time_hour, approved_at_time_minute, expire_at_date, expire_at_time_hour, expire_at_time_minute
```

And yes, these attributes aren't accessible for usual user. But I would like them to be accessible in admin panel. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `with_role` method of  `inherited_resources` that is used by active admin to assign a scope to certain attributes such that they are only accessible to active admin but not to general users.

Check out the [Scoped Mass Assignment with Active Admin](http://ejholmes.github.io/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html).

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, but these solutions doesn't work for me. I added `with_role :admin` to the `controller` section and `:as => :admin` in model. I don't know how can I investigate why it doesn't work.

Comment: My fault. I forgot about one field in attr_accessible.